# Point to site configuration VNET connection VPN accessing

Tags: vpn, routing, azure, radius

I have two vnet created with **2 virtual networks gateways(vnet1 and vnet2)** having point to site configuration one with the radius authentication and other with route based vpn configuration .I have peered both vnets and I am able to access vm from both virtual networks.But my issue is can we access **vm1** from **vnet1** while connecting vpn from **vnet2** .??

**For example** let me explain further we have **2 vnets -vnet1 vnet2** contains each **vms vm1(vnet1) and vm2(vnet2**).I have two vpn connections  **vpn1(certificate based-route based)** and **vpn2(radius authentication)** and my occurs when I tried to connect vpn2 and tries to acces vm1(private ip) am not able to access as it shows destination not reachable .Also the same case occurs when I tried to connect **vpn1** and tries to access **vm2(private ip)**.While if i login to **vm1(private ip)** and tries to access **vm2(private ip)** am able to access and vice versa.So correct if I wrong can we access **vm2** from **vnet2** from a **home location** connecting **vpn1** using private ip or is there are any other method that can achieve these mechanism?

Comment: If the reply is helpful, you can check mark or let me know if you need help further in this case.

Comment: seem  you answer doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

> But my issue is can we access vm1 from vnet1 while connecting vpn from
>   vnet2 .??

Yes, you can do that via [Configure VPN gateway transit for virtual network peering](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-peering-gateway-transit). The gateway transit allows the peered virtual networks to use the same Azure VPN gateway. So you can use VPN access VM1 from VNet2. The constraint is that the VPN gateway can only be in the virtual network using Resource Manager deployment model. Also, Gateway transit is currently not supported with global virtual network peering(regions of Peered VNets are different)

Moreover, In this case, you only need to have one P2S VPN connection. Once the peered VNets changes or VPN connection settings get updates, the VPN client package must be downloaded and installed again in order for the changes to be applied to the client.

Comment: thanks for the reply but it's seems peering only helps when there no virtual network gateway configured in vnets.That means you can peer using on of the virtual network gateway shared  and act as same network but my question seems  have taken different direction than which @ Nancy Xiong - MSFT refered

Comment: yes, in this case you only need one of virtual network gateway in peered network.

Comment: As I have mentioned above since am have already two virtual network gateways how could I conncet both vnets so that While  accessing vpn from home location from vpn1 ( to access vm2 of vnet2 using private ip)?..if you haven't got clear idea  about the question I can elaborate in detail

Comment: I know your question, I just post the certain suggestion that you only need one vpn gateway to access the vm1 and vm2 from both vnets from your home location. If two vpn gateways without gateway transit, it seems that you need configure some [routes(UDR)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview) to route traffic from on-premise to the second peered network, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks @Nancy for letting me know .I will check it with UDR .

Comment: @Anuroop sorry. it's my fault,  Currently, It seems that it's not supported for accessing the peered second network via P2S VPN gateway on the Azure. If you need to access another VNet, you can create an S2S VPN connection.